# AngleSharp "iconfiguration does not contain a definition for WithRequesters"

Tags: c#, httpclient, anglesharp

> Error    CS1061  'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'WithRequesters' and no accessible extension method 'WithRequesters' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Got this error while writing the following code:

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;
using AngleSharp.Io;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExcelLinksChecker
{
    internal class WebHandler
    {
        internal async Task CheckLinkAsync(LinkCell linkCell)
        {
            try
            {

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");
                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
                    var config = Configuration.Default
                        .WithRequesters(handler) // red underline here
                        .WithCookies()
                        .WithDefaultLoader();
                    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
                    var document = await context.OpenAsync(linkCell.Link);
                    var readButton = document.QuerySelector("a.button button--green button-read");
                    Console.WriteLine(readButton.Text());
```

Comment: Which .NET version are you running?

Comment: I use .NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to install AngleSharp **and** AngleSharp.Io. The given extension comes from `AngleSharp.Io`, which is an extension library.

More information: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Io

Comment: You confuse a namespace with a library.